# How to set a2dp sink as a default (android 7.1)

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-7.1-nougat, a2dp

We made a custom board which has Android 7.1                operating system as a our custom board  must act to a reciver with bluetooth(while a2dp sink profile in bluetooth can do this), but we have do many works over weeks on it , but it still not work, so i'd like to ask somebody who know or had similar expirence on it could help.
Android 7.1 used the fluoride Bluetooth stack

```
our works :
1. packages/apps/Bluetooth/res/values/config.xml
<bool name="profile_supported_a2dp">true</bool>
<bool name="profile_supported_a2dp_sink">true</bool>
2. android/platform/system/bt/include/bt_target.h 
#define BTA_AV_SINK_INCLUDED TRUE
```

Android device as a receiver for A2DP profile, but it seems didn't work.so anybody could help.
I didn't check with
`<bool name="profile_supported_a2dp">false</bool>`
If both a2dp profile role like source and sink are enable then it will take default as a a2dp source instead of a2dp sink ?
So that's why its not work?

Comment: Currently working on the same issue. Looks like You cannot have both profiles enabled.